# Avoiding too much "self." when working with classes methods

Tags: python, class

I have created this class that works as expected, I want only to expose one method, `get_enriched_data`so the other are pretty much private w/ the underscore.

The functionality works, just pretty convinced I am not doing the most pythonic/OOP way:

```
class MergeClients:
    def __init__(self,source_df,extra_info_df,type_f):
        self.df_all = pd.merge(source_df,extra_info_df, on='clientID', how='left')
        self.avg_age = self._get_avg_age()
        self.type_f = 'Medium'
        
    
    def _filter_by_age(self, age):
        return self.df_all[self.df_all['Age'] > age]
    
    def _filter_by_family_type(self, f_type):
        return self.df_all[self.df_all['familyType'] == f_type]
    
    def _get_avg_age(self):
        return self.df_all['Age'].mean()
    
    def get_enriched_data(self):
        self.df_all = self._filter_by_age(self.avg_age)
        self.df_all=self._filter_by_family_type(self.type_f)
        return self.df_all
```

But I find the code looks so ugly with so many self references, for example in the `get_enriched_data`method there are three self references per line, how can I correct this? Any direction on how to correctly Python classes is welcome.

Edit:

Example of working code:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'clientID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'Name':['Peter','Margaret','Marc','Alice','Maria']})

extra_info = pd.DataFrame({'clientID':[1,2,3,4,5],'Age':[19,35,18,65,57],'familyType':['Big','Medium','Single','Medium','Medium']})

family_stats = MergeClients(main_df,extra_info,'Medium')

family_filtered = family_stats.get_enriched_data()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some odd things about your code. I will point out one thing about instances: every method has access to all attributes, so you don't always need to pass them as parameters:

```py
class MergeClients:
    def __init__(self,source_df,extra_info_df,type_f):
        self.df_all = pd.merge(source_df,extra_info_df, on='clientID', how='left')
        self.avg_age = self._get_avg_age()
        self.type_f = 'Medium'
        
    
    def _filter_by_age(self):  #No need for age param
        return self.df_all[self.df_all['Age'] > self.avg_age]
    
    def _filter_by_family_type(self):  #No need for f_type param
        return self.df_all[self.df_all['familyType'] == self.type_f]
    
    def _get_avg_age(self):
        return self.df_all['Age'].mean()
    
    def get_enriched_data(self):
        self.df_all = self._filter_by_age()
        self.df_all = self._filter_by_family_type()
        return self.df_all
```

Since the two methods in question: `_filter_by_age()` and `_filter_by_family_type()` are private by convention, this means that clients of your class are not expected to call them. So if only other methods of this class call these methods and only the ones you have shown, then there is no need to pass parameters which are already attributes.

Alternatively there is the argument that for other private methods where sometimes they should use attributes, but at other times they should take a parameter, then I would make those methods take a parameter as you had originally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so many odd things that are odd in my code, could you point me to the right direction (website/book) to learn? Thanks

Comment: I would look for Kent Beck/Ron Jeffries for [simple design](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BeckDesignRules.html), the GOF for [Design Patterns](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GangOfFour.html)  and Martin Fowler for [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Functions declared within a Python Class can be effectively made 'private' by preceding the name with double underscore. For example:

```
class Clazz():
  def __work(self):
    print('Working')
  def work(self):
    self.__work()

c = Clazz()
c.work()
c.__work()
```

The output of this would be:

Working
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/G-DRIVE Thunderbolt 3/PythonStuff/play.py", line 575, in 
c = Clazz()
AttributeError: 'Clazz' object has no attribute '__work'

In other words, the __work function has been 'hidden'

Comment: has nothing to do with 'private', as the function can still be accessed. It just gets a diferent name: `c._Clazz__work()` . It attaches the classname to the function to prevent collisions.

Comment: I said 'effectively made private'. The point about using the dunder prefix is to discourage direct use of that variable. Knowing how the name mangling works means that this can be overcome. Of course there is no such thing as a real private variable in a Python class

Comment: The purpose is only to avoid accidental name clashes with names defined by subclasses. If there are no subclasses, there is no point in using `__`